# 'ref' is not defined no-undef I would like to try to load image from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using React and trying to fetch an image URL from firebase Storage, displaying the image.
but
'ref' is not defined  no-undef
is occurred.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference

the official says "ref() is used to get image URL"

firebaseconfig.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import "firebase/storage"

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
//connection information
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.firestore();

export const storage = firebase.storage();
```

```
  const getImage = () =>{
    ref = storage.ref().child('/img/thumbs/super_potato.jpeg');
    ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      document.getElementById('image').src = url;
    });
  }

  return (
      <div className="container section project-details">
            <img id = "iamge" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define `ref` before assigning a value to it.

Change:

```
ref = storage.ref().child('/img/thumbs/super_potato.jpeg');
```

to

```
let ref = storage.ref().child('/img/thumbs/super_potato.jpeg');
```

You can read more about `no-undef` on [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-undef)